# To solve self consistent equations by simultaneously plotting them

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

How can we solve a pair of equations that have to be solved self-consistently (even by plotting them simultaneously) .

```
y = 1/2 + 1/\[Pi] ArcTan[c (0.5 - x)];
x = 1/2 + 1/\[Pi] ArcTan[c (0.5 - y)];
```

For `c=0.5` we must have a plot as below one in which the vertical axis is `y` and horizontal one is devoted to `x`.

[image]

For `c=Pi` we must have

[image]

Comment: FindRoot for solving and ContourPlot for plotting

Comment: I wanted to plot the first function y vs x ordinary and by `InverseFunction[f][y]` I wanted to plot the second one (x vs y). For the second one the output plot is not symmetric relative to bisectrix of the first quarter of the coordination plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With[{c = 0.5},
 ContourPlot[{
   y == 1/2 + 1/π ArcTan[c (0.5 - x)],
   x == 1/2 + 1/π ArcTan[c (0.5 - y)]
   }, 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[{c = π},
 ContourPlot[{
   y == 1/2 + 1/π ArcTan[c (0.5 - x)],
   x == 1/2 + 1/π ArcTan[c (0.5 - y)]
   }, 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One can even use `MeshFunctions` to mark the intersection point.